# Decoupling issue with DC Motor?

Tags: arduino, capacitor, dc-motor, attiny

I have the following circuit :

[image]

That's basically everything, excepted a button on DC1 to turn on/off the motor, but shouldn't impact.

The problem is, I was prototyping with the DC Motor on the LM7805 and the other parts powered by the +5V of the arduino I was using to program the ATTiny45. I assume the DC Motor resistance at "full speed" is \$50\Omega\$. (Around 0.1A at 5V).

Now I've moved everything on the LM7805 and when I turn on the motors the ATTiny shutdown after few seconds. The time he stays up depend on the value of RV1 who manage the speed of the motor, controlled by the attiny with the BC337 transistor controlled with PWM.

So, I started to use bigger caps but I can't stabalize the circuit. I've tried with 4700uF on C1/C2/C3 and the improvement is not soo great, a bit better but still shutdown pretty quickly. They are placed as close as possible to "their pins".

So, what can I do to leave the motor at that place ? Put it on a separated LM7805 ? Add a capacitor somewhere ? (I really need to put it on a voltage regulator)

Comment: Can you use a separate voltage regulator for the motor?

Comment: @alexan_e : As mentioned in the question I was considering that, but I would prefer to do it in another way (if it's possible)

Comment: Actually you said `I really need to put it on a voltage regulator`, did you mean a single regulator? Actually you already proposed a second regulator `Put it on a separated LM7805 ?` have you tested if it solves the problem?

Comment: Yes, that solve the problem. By "I really need to put it on a voltage regulator" I mean "I can't put the DC Motor directly on the battery output, before the voltage regulator". I need to drive them with 5V. I proposed the second regulator as a kind of "last solution", but I really would like to avoid that.

Comment: Maybe a Schottky diode in the mcu supply line with a capacitor in the mcu line will help (so that the capacitor charge feeds only the mcu) but it will add a small voltage drop for the mcu supply, would that  be a problem? The voltage drop can be as low as 0.3v with a diode like [1N5817](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/1N/1N5818.pdf) at 100mA

Comment: As a general rule, if at all possible you should attempt to run the motor without a (linear) voltage regulator: As the motor current rises, so does the heat generated at the linear regulator. Next, the motor will draw maximum current not at full speed, but when stalled i.e. not able to move. At full speed it will draw the minimum current. Also, there doesn't seem to be a decoupling cap across the motor itself - Add one 10 uF capacitor between the motor terminals, and consider adding two more, one from each motor terminal to the ground rail - make sure caps are soldered close to the terminals.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh : Damn, caps on the motor terminals... I forgot them and that solve the issue... (The most annoying is that I've done that in my previous project...) Time to rest a bit. Thank you, you can post it as answer if you want :)

Comment: @AnindoGhosh : But in that case, what method should I use to drive them with 5V when the voltage supply is higher ?

Comment: @EmmanuelIstace Either drive them at a lower duty cycle using PWM, use a current-limited drive rather than voltage-limited, use a motor rated for the available raw voltage, or (least preferable) use a switching regulator instead of a linear one.

Comment: An alternative or addition to Anindo's solution is to place a low value resistor in the processor Vdd line with a cap at the uC - electrically where C3 is BUT connected close to the uC pins. If uC was known to draw say 30 mA abs max then adding a series R that dropped say 0.1V max will provide an impedance to allow the cap to decouple the Vdd supply. For 0.1V, 30 MA R=V/I = 0.1 / .030 =~ 3.3 Ohms. A 4R7 or 10R would be OK. 10 uF and 10R gives abound 1 kHz corner frequency and 100 uF correspondingly lower. This plus a motor cap should help muchly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution given by @AnindoGosh

[image]

Adding capacitors C5 and C4 solve the issue.

Comment: The suggestion included a third cap which is not swown in the schematic, `10 uF capacitor between the motor terminals, across the motor itself`

Comment: The 2 x 10 uF are effectively a 5 uF across the motor. Not as much capacitance as 10 uF directly, but the value is fairly arbitrary. "Just" a cap across the motor would probably have worked.